# Firefox 50 and Selenium 3.0 not working via Codeception tests

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

My acceptance tests were working, then I upgraded Firefox, and now they don't. I was using Firefox 46 and Selenium 2.53. Now I'm getting the following error:

"The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases"

The issue is, *everything* I've found talks about setting the system property, through what I assume, is Java. Codeception is PHP. Has anyone else encountered this and how did you resolve it?

In my acceptance.suite.yml file I added the marionette: false line, which does actually trigger Firefox to open (it won't open otherwise), but nothing happens afterward.

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
  - \Helper\Acceptance
  - WebDriver:
      browser: firefox
      url: https://www.myexample.com/
      capabilities:
        marionette: false
```

Comment: This is exactly the same information I mentioned I've found in 100 different places, but no where does it describe how to solve the problem I'm having. I would down vote this comment if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not about Codeception configuration, but about the way you start Selenium.
You have to pass a correct path to geckodriver as a parameter.

`java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=~/geckodriver ~/selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar`

In Selenium 2 -D parameters could be given after jar file. Selenium 3 is stricter and parameters must be given before jar file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it this way. Another suggestion I got offline was to add the  gecko driver to my system PATH, which works as well.